# IIS 10 404 error with minified JS and CSS files

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I am setting up a website on Server 2016 with IIS 10 and any minified files (.min.css or .min.js) are returning a 404.0 error. It looks like the ".min" portion of the URL is being stripped out for some reason. For example, if I try and access the URL below:

`http://localhost/reporting/Resources/components/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js`

I get a 404 and it tells me this is the "Requested URL" (notice how it's just *jquery-ui.js* instead of *jquery-ui.min.js*):

`http://localhost:80/reporting/Resources/components/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui.js`

The folder only has the minified version of the file so it makes sense why I'm getting a 404, but why is it trying to get the normal .js file in the first place?

[**Screenshot of the full error and details here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3nX4.png)

[image: Screenshot of the full error and details here]

Deploying the same site to Server 2008 or 2012 I have no issue, but on the two Server 2016/IIS 10 machines I have tested I am seeing the problem. Because of that, I'm thinking there is a IIS 10 configuration somewhere that needs to be adjusted.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or know what might need to be changed with the IIS setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this as I just spent two days finding and fixing the problem.

If you install IIS6 components on the same server hosting IIS10, it will start to work. IIS10 should have catered for this most basic feature OOB in the release of Server 2016. [Screenshot of IIS6 components required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEoqt.png)

My issue specifically related to sharepoint 2019. My CSS wouldn't work for the Master page I had created, but did work on another server in the farm.. found it pure chance.. hope it helps!